# Pandas: Create new dataframe that averages duplicates from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `my_df` with column duplicates, e..g

```
foo bar foo hello
0   1   1   5
1   1   2   5
2   1   3   5
```

I would like to create another dataframe that averages the duplicates:

```
foo bar hello
0.5   1   5
1.5   1   5
2.5   1   5
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

So far I have managed to identify duplicates:

```
my_columns = my_df.columns
my_duplicates = print [x for x, y in collections.Counter(my_columns).items() if y > 1]
```

By I don't know how to ask Pandas to average them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) the column index and take the [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
Out[11]:
   bar  foo  hello
0    1  0.5      5
1    1  1.5      5
2    1  2.5      5
```

A somewhat trickier example is if there is a non numeric column:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   foo  bar  foo hello
0    0    1    1     a
1    1    1    2     a
2    2    1    3     a
```

*The above will raise: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.* Definitely *not* going to win *any* prizes for efficiency, but here's generic method to do in this case:

```
In [22]: dupes = df.columns.get_duplicates()

In [23]: dupes
Out[23]: ['foo']

In [24]: pd.DataFrame({d: df[d] for d in df.columns if d not in dupes})
Out[24]:
   bar hello
0    1     a
1    1     a
2    1     a

In [25]: pd.concat(df.xs(d, axis=1) for d in dupes).groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
Out[25]:
   foo
0  0.5
1  1.5
2  2.5

In [26]: pd.concat([Out[24], Out[25]], axis=1)
Out[26]:
   foo  bar hello
0  0.5    1     a
1  1.5    1     a
2  2.5    1     a
```

I think the thing to take away is avoid column duplicates... or perhaps that I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks, I get `"No numeric types to aggregate"`, but all my columns (except the first one, which holds `object` for strings) hold `float64` types. Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: And it turns out that I can't call `mydf.drop()` to remove that `str` column since I get: `"Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"`

Comment: @user815423426 hmmm this seems to make it a bit trickier (I was sure previously mean etc. ignored non numeric columns...)